# Need text editor that can save locally AND via FTP for Linux - switching from EditPlus on windows

Tags: linux, php, html

I just switched from Windows to Linux. I've been using EditPlus for many years mainly because of it's ability to save locally, and then send the file via FTP, with easy keyboard shortcuts (ctrl-s to save, ctrl-alt-s to ftp).

I also need syntax highlighting and basic code editing features. Is there anything for Linux that can do this? I don't want to run EditPlus via Wine

PLEASE READ BELOW

---

I need to save locally and remotely simultaneously, or at least with a few keystrokes. I already know of plenty of ways to edit remote files.

---

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a program that mounts an directory over FTP, for example `curlftpfs`. Then use any text editor. I recommend Kate if you are not into editors like vim or emacs, but Gedit will suffice if you don't want to install the KDE libraries.

Comment: Will that setup save locally and remotely at the same time? 

Is vim able to save locally and remotely at the same time?

Comment: I don't know. I personally don't use it. I think it only saves remotely. But if you are asking about vim, it may have a plugin that supports saving files over FTP, even without curlftpfs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use VIM

```
vim ftp://username@yourdomain.com//the/path/to/yourfile.php
```

There is a Wiki describing editing files via ftp, rcp, scp, or http.

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Editing_remote_files_via_scp_in_vim

Comment: there's lots of editors that allow editing of remote files. I'm looking for a way to save locally AND remotely either at the same time or with a few keystrokes without having to program a script for every file I work on.

Comment: :w - write it to where it came from
:w foo.txt - write it locally. 

seems like "with a few keystrokes" for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not an vi/vim person, you could try Emacs with [AngeFtp](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AngeFtp)